# How do I match a single equals sign with regular expressions?

Tags: c#, regex, match

I have the following expression:

```
if(x == a+b) b=a+2; else x = 1;
```

I need to match a single equal sign =. Not ==, not ==== and so on. And it should match without spaces around the sign, just equals sign. 
I have quite a monster-like reg. expression which matches everything in the code above, everything I need but the single equals sign. 
Here is my expr:

```
 /\bif\b|\belse\b|\(|\)|\+|\-|\*|\\|\>|\<|\<=|\>=|(?<![!=])[!=]=(?!=)|([a-zA-Z][a-zA-z0-9_]*)|(\d+\.?\d*)/g
```

Although it may be not optimal variant (I'm sure it's not:)), I need to add the "equals match" through the pipe | into my expression.

Strange it may seem, but I didn't find the solution searching through stackoverflow questions...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use a [look-ahead and look-behind zero length assertion](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444). The regex you are looking for should be `(?<!=)=(?!=)`. This demands that we find a `=` not preceeded by an equals sign `(?<!=)` and not followed by an equals sign `(?!=)`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the most simple i can come up with:

```
(?<!=)=(?!=)
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggested answers with look-ahead and look-behind might fail with empty strings. Instead, use `(^|[^=])=($|[^=])`:

- `(^|[^=])`: Either the start of the string or not an `=` character
- `=`: The `=` character
- `($|[^=])`: Either the end of the string or not an `=` character